# React: Focus input on keyboard click (ctrl F / cmd F) instead of triggering Browser Search

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, use-ref

Morning peeps,
I am trying to focus a search input in my application when someone presses CTRL+F or CMD+F instead of triggering the browser's search, and I would like to ask if that's even possible. An implementation that I found online but doesn't work obviously is this:

```
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) {
      if (document.getElementsById('search').not(':focus')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Search is not in focus');
        document.getElementsById('search').focus();
      } else {
        console.log('Default action of CtrlF');
        return true;
      }
    }
  });
```

I have also tried to use the `useRef()` from React in order to reach the input and focus it afterwards, but couldn't make it work. Any hints, ideas, code snippets that could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change **getElementsById** to **getElementById**
2. use document.activeElement to check current focus element (**much better approach**)

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) {
    if (document.getElementById('search') !== document.activeElement) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Search is not in focus');
      document.getElementById('search').focus();
    } else {
      console.log('Default action of CtrlF');
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```